# Client can't connect to RabbitMQ server on localhost

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu, rabbitmq, ubuntu-12.04

I installed fresh RabbitMQ 3.1.3 on ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS by apt-get, and try to start consumers on the same server, but I have connection problem:

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]         
Error Connecting to server(113): No route to host
```

There is status of working server:

```
Status of node rabbit@ns1 ...
[{pid,2106},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.1.3"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
                        {xmerl,"XML parser","1.2.10"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [rq:4] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,27728944},
          {connection_procs,2704},
          {queue_procs,5408},
          {plugins,0},
          {other_proc,9021680},
          {mnesia,60016},
          {mgmt_db,0},
          {msg_index,31144},
          {other_ets,770736},
          {binary,1968},
          {code,14560395},
          {atom,1356081},
          {other_system,1918812}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,1262847590},
 {disk_free_limit,1000000000},
 {disk_free,214706556928},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,924},
                    {total_used,3},
                    {sockets_limit,829},
                    {sockets_used,1}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,125}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,1265}]
...done.
```

I don't have any limitations by iptables (ports):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And `etc/hosts` is OK.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
{IP-ADDRESS} ns1.***.org  ns1
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Whay I'm doing wrong?

UPD:
`sudo netstat -nlp | grep 5672` returns: `tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      2106/beam.smp`

From rabbitMQ logs:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 2-Jul-2013::16:05:11 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 2-Jul-2013::16:05:11 ===
Server startup complete; 0 plugins started.

=INFO REPORT==== 2-Jul-2013::16:35:04 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.1130.0> (127.0.0.1:44112 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Jul-2013::16:35:14 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1130.0> (127.0.0.1:44112 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
{handshake_timeout,handshake}
```

I tried to change `localhost` to `ip6-localhost` and sometimes when try to starting consumer, it returns:

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]             
Error Connecting to server(110): Connection timed out
```

**UPD2** If I start consumer with debug flag and `--env=prod` (`php .../app/console rabbitmq:consumer -w -d consumer_name`), consumer starts and working.

Comment: please, attach script source code you are trying to connect with

Comment: I'll try to start consumer from Symfony2 console by [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/rabbitmqbundle) with parameters of connection localhost:5672, vhost: /

Comment: Can you connect to web admin interface (if enabled) on port 15672 by default? Did you explicitly pass connection arguments or use default one?

Comment: I'll try to wget from console on server, and get ~$ wget localhost:15672
--2013-07-02 16:30:26--  http://localhost:15672/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:15672... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: I use default connection arguments.

Comment: can you provide config and probably turn on webadmin panel just add this to your config: {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 15672}]}]}

Comment: I turn on with sudo `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`, but telnet localhost 15672 Trying 127.0.0.1... telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: hmmm, drop me a message in skype (same login), it's an interesting problem, stack-overflow doesn't like long discussions in comments

Comment: See more in depth answer to duplicate question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828937/php-client-cant-connect-to-rabbitmq-server-on-localhost/27740555#27740555

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was fixed with reconfiguring listen address from 0.0.0.0:5672 to 127.0.0.1:5672 and small security fixes in OS.

Comment: See more in depth answer to this question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828937/php-client-cant-connect-to-rabbitmq-server-on-localhost/27740555#27740555

Answer (score 3):

If the necessary ports are not open on the rabbitmq server, you get this "No route to host" error when the client tries to connect.

To fix it, make sure the ports are open, if not, open them:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5672 --syn -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5673 --syn -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 15672 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

This sets it on temporally.  Set it permanently with your iptables.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Then restart:

```
sudo service iptables restart
```